# JavaFX listener to a visible part of VBox

Tags: javafx, listener, vbox, borderpane

I have a JavaFX **VBox** inside a **BorderPane** (central). The content of the VBox is calculated using some business logic and it depends on the height of the **visible** part of the vbox.

So basically I need a listener watching changes of the visible height of the vbox = height of the central part of the border pane.

The following code demonstrates what I have tried:

```java
public class HelloFX extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.boundsInParentProperty()
            .addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                    System.out.println(newValue.getHeight()));

    Button button = new Button("ADD LINE");
    button.setPrefHeight(25);
    button.setOnAction(event ->
        vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("line")));

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(vbox);
    borderPane.setTop(button);

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 100, 100);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

BorderPane with simple button on the top position and VBox on the central. The button click adds one line to vBox. Total scene height is 100, 25 is the button height and the rest (75) is the vBox.

I'm looking for some listener to report changes of the height of the central part of border pane. So in my example it should always print "75" no matter how many lines I have added to the vBox. The **only event changing** the value should be **resizing** the whole window. In reality once the vBox is filled my listener reports increasing height values. Apparently the height property includes the invisible part of the vbox.

**EDIT**

Finally I've found some solution - placing the vBox in the **ScrollPane** with **disabled scrollbars**. Then I can simply listen on the height property of the scrollpane and everything works as expected.

```java
public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setContent(vbox);
        scrollPane.heightProperty()
                .addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                        System.out.println(newValue));

        Button button = new Button("ADD LINE");
        button.setPrefHeight(25);
        button.setOnAction(event ->
                vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("line")));

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(scrollPane);
        borderPane.setTop(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 100, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: you might consider to post your solution as an answer and accept it - this way it'll be more prominently visible to future searches :)

Comment: Thank you. I consider my solution still a kind of dirty workaround. Hope someone will come with something better.